# How to customise a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame, titlebar

I want to make a window with customised titlebar(like my own color and my own icons)

Something like we see in the "Stickynotes" of Windows os.

Comment: Look to a custom PLAF & [`JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you wants somthing like Stikynotes use `JWindow` class. Because, A JWindow is a container that can be displayed anywhere on the user's desktop. It does not have the title bar, window-management buttons, or other trimmings associated with a JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an undecorated jframe but if you really want the buttons and backgrounds to be custom then you should use javaFX.